# How to return an object in jsx and use in immediately with out depending on setState as its Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to do DRF (Django Rest Framework) with React so I am using the fetch() with required attributes to hit the API endpoint and getting some data. Now in my case, I need to hit two API endpoints. But I wanted to reuse the fetch() by putting it in a function which will return an object and I'll save using setState.

My problem is the endpoint URL for the second API call is in the object returned by the first API call.

Example:
fetch(enpoint1, data) -> returns {name: 'something', url: 'endpoint2'}

if I do setState here the object is not updated as setState is Asynchronous and so I cannot use it immediately.

I might have a super silly mistake. Any advice on the "way I am doing it" or "on how to correct it" would be appreciated.

```
  componentDidMount() {
  let currentComponent = this;
  try {
    const data = {username: 'username', password: 'password'};
//gets me the token
    fetch(URL(Just example), {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(data){
      return data.token
    }).then(function(token){
      var project_object = currentComponent.fetchFunction(currentComponent.props.endpoint, token)
      console.log(project_object)
      //This is UNDEFINED
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

```
fetchFunction(endPoint, token) {
    let currentComponent = this;
    var object = {}
    console.log(endPoint)
    try {
      //fetch for project object
      fetch(endPoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'authorization': 'Token ' + token
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(object){
        console.log(object)
        object = object
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    return object
}
```